# Android 11.0: How to delete a file with Storage Access Framework?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, delete-file, storage-access-framework

I'm trying to delete a file with it's Uri, but I don't understand how to add flags on this file (I'm new on android).

My application manages both media files and others files.

I managed to delete the media files with the documentation of the Mediastore API. But for others files, it says to use the storage access framework.

So, I get file's Uri like this:

```
Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL), id);
```

Then I want to delete it like this:

```
DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(getContentResolver(), uri);
```

However, it doesn't work cause I don't add FLAG_SUPPORTS_DELETE to the file. And I don't understand how to do that.

I read the storage access framework documentation several times as well as the various posts on stackoverflow, but I did not find anything that could help me (I am new to android).

Comment: "However, it doesn't work cause I don't add FLAG_SUPPORTS_DELETE to the file" -- *you* do not add the flag. The documents provider would be adding the flag. In your case, you are not using the Storage Access Framework to get the `Uri`. Hence, you cannot use `DocumentsContract` to delete it. You seem to be working with `MediaStore.Files`, so perhaps you should stick with your `MediaStore` approach for this content as well. Otherwise, you need to use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, and `DocumentFile` to work with the Storage Access Framework.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't understand why my approach can't work. A uri remains the same if I access it with the mediastore API or with the storage access framework? How else can I delete a non media file with the Mediastore API? To delete my media files I use this code: PendingIntent removePI = MediaStore.createDeleteRequest (getContentResolver (), currentSelectedFiles);
         startIntentSenderForResult (removePI.getIntentSender (), DELETE_REQUEST, null, 0, 0, 0, null);
However, when I try to delete a non media file with this code, I get an error telling me that I can only delete media files.

Comment: "A uri remains the same if I access it with the mediastore API or with the storage access framework?" -- not really. That is equivalent to saying that because you have admin access to your own Web server that, you must also have admin access to Facebook, because they are both using `https` URLs. "when I try to delete a non media file with this code, I get an error telling me that I can only delete media files" -- then use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, and `DocumentFile` to work with the Storage Access Framework.

Comment: On Android 11 and maybe before, media store uries can be converted to saf uries.

Comment: @CommonsWare @blackapps Thank you for your answers. So, is there no way to delete non media files with the mediastore api? Example of uris that crash my application: `content://media/external/file/14502, content://media/external/file/14647`. With the following error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All requested items must be Media items`.

Comment: "is there no way to delete non media files with the mediastore api?" -- frankly, I have never tried it.

Comment: @blackapps I search on stack how to convert mediastore URI to Storage Access Framework URI, but I found nothing. Can you tell me how to do that please.

Comment: Somerhing like MediaStore.convert..... or .to...

Comment: `Example of uris that crash my application:`... Well cath that exception i would say.

Comment: @CommonsWare @blackapps if i understand correctly, i have to go through the storage access framework to delete a non media file under `android 11.0`? Or is there another way? Knowing that I also have the path of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I can provide an answer to my problem.

My application aims to list all duplicate files, and delete them through a user interface.

For the media files, I did not encounter any great difficulties, the Mediastore API is relatively easy to use.

However, for non-media files it was very complicated. Indeed, I first managed to list them via the mediastore API, but I quickly realized that it was not possible to delete them with this API.

So I then opted for saf (storage access framework), but after several rereading of the doc, I realized that I could not access the Download directory. Directory essential for the proper functioning of my application.

Then, I then tried to combine both the Mediastore API and the File API. I recovered the path of the files via mediastore, and I deleted them via the File API. However, small problem, the files were deleted from my app fine, but I could still access and view them through google's Files app.

Back to the wall, I didn't know how to get out of it. Being new to android I have no experience (this is the first application I made). But I still found a "trick" to delete a non media file:

```
getContentResolver().delete(path, null, null);
```

This line of code allows me to delete a file (both from my application, and from google's Files application). However, I have no idea whether this is a bad practice or not at all. I also saw that I can use this to delete a file:

```
getApplicationContext().deleteFile(filename);
```

But I still don't know if this is a bad practice.

Here is my journey to "solve" this problem: how to delete a non media file without using saf (storage access framework) (because unable to access the Download directory)?

If you have any remarks, advice or other, I am interested. I'm also curious if you have any other techniques to solve my problem, and if my solution is good or bad.

Be indulgent, i'm new on android, and I code on android 11 (android R) only.

Thank you very much for your reading.

Comment: So is thr path and or filenames uri's or just paths from getexternalstorage?